# ASP.Net MVC Wildcard Mappings IIS 6.0 - Page Can Not be Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, wildcard-mapping

I added wildcard mappings to my website in IIS 6.0 so that my MVC application works properly but now I get a page can not be found for every request. Once wildcard mappings are inserted I can not browse to a test html file I created or any of my routes.

The site works fine when the wildcard mappings are off and I create a application extention called .mvc which is then used in my routes however I woupld prefer not using the extension in the Url.

Here are some highlights of my setup, server, and application:

Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0:

.Net 3.5 SP1

Bin deployment for the MVC dll's

Server has mutiple sites running on it. With this particular one being set up as its own site (not a virtual directory).

The site uses forms authentication

When setting up the wildcard mappings I unchecked "verify file exists" and mapped to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.050727\aspnet_isapi.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service extensions where pointing to framework64.  As soon as the wildcard mapping was pointing to the correct folder (framework64 instead of framework) it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Url rewriting can help you to solve the problem. I've implemented solution allowing to deploy MVC application at any IIS version even when virtual hosting is used.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/iis-aspnet-url-rewriting.aspx